# Are there processes of electric discharge to oxide As(III) into As(V)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state, ionization-energy

I want to know if there were any known experiment of electric discharge to oxyde the ion arsenic(III) into the ion arsenic(V).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > The feasibility of the electro-removal of arsenate (As(V)) and
   >   arsenite (As(III)) from aqueous solutions via **capacitive
   >   deionization** was investigated. The effects of applied voltage
   >   (0.0-1.2V) and initial concentration (0.1-200 mgL(-1)) on arsenic
   >   removal were examined. As evidenced, an enhancement of arsenic removal
   >   can be achieved by capacitive deionization.[...]
2. > Water‐soluble poly[glycidyl methacrylate N‐methyl d‐glucamine],
   >   P(GMA‐NMG), was synthesized and purified by ultrafiltration membranes.
   >   It was subsequently used for arsenic removal by **coupling
   >   electro‐oxidation (EO) and polymer‐enhanced ultrafiltration (PEU)
   >   processes.** In the EO‐PEU combined process, P(GMA‐NMG) was first used
   >   as supporting electrolyte during the exhaustive electro‐oxidation of
   >   As(III) to As(V) and then it was used to remove As(V) from aqueous
   >   solution through PEU.
3. > **Electrochemical oxidation of arsenic(III). A consecutive
   >   electron-transfer reaction**
   >
   > The reaction is based on two consecutive one-electron-transfer-step
   >   reaction of form:
   >
   > $$\ce{ As(III) <-> As(IV) <-> As(V)}$$
   >
   > $\ce{As(IV)}$ being the intermediate which has been postulated from the
   >   kinetic effect of the homogeneous reaction.

**References**

1. Fan CS, et al. and J Hazard Mater. "Electro-removal of arsenic(III) and arsenic(V) from aqueous solutions by capacitive deionization"
   **2016**.([link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/27037475/))
2. Ozgur Arar, Nalan Kabay, Julio Sánchez , Bernabé L. Rivas, Marek Bryjak, Carlos Peña
   "Removal of arsenic from water by combination of electro‐oxidation and polymer enhanced ultrafiltration" 15 October **2013** DOI: [https://doi.org/10.1002/ep.11876](https://aiche.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/ep.11876)
3. Henry A. Catherino "Electrochemical oxidation of arsenic(III). A consecutive electron-transfer reaction" J. Phys. Chem.1967,7,12,268-274, January 1, **1967** DOI: [https://doi.org/10.1021/j100861a010](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/j100861a010)